# make canvasjs line chart oval (not straight line) in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, charts, canvasjs

Unfortunately I have a project where I'm using ionic 1. In this project, I draw charts with chartjs. But in this chart, the lines are moving in a straight line. How can I fix this? I want to plot it like a sine graph.

```
<div ng-controller="example" data-linetension="0.7" id="hr" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var dps = [{x: 1, y: 10, color: "red"}, {x: 2, y: 13, color: "red"}, {x: 3, y: 18, color: "red"}, {x: 4, y: 20, color: "red"}, {x: 5, y: 17, color: "red"},{x: 6, y: 10, color: "red"}, {x: 7, y: 13, color: "red"}, {x: 8, y: 18, color: "red"}, {x: 9, y: 20, color: "red"}, {x: 10, y: 17, color: "red"}];   //dataPoints. 

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("hr",{
            type: 'line',
            axisY: {                        
                title: "Sayı",
                labelFontColor: "red"
            },
            lineTension: 0.4,
                    tension: 0.4,
            data: [{
                type: "line",
                lineColor: "green",
                pointColor: "white",
                dataPoints : dps,lineTension: 0.4,
                tension: 0.4,
                datasets: [{
                    lineTension: 0.4,
                    tension: 0.4,
                    bezierCurve : true,
                  }]
            }],
            lineTension: 0.4,
                    tension: 0.4,
            options: {
                bezierCurve : true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            type: 'linear',
                            display: false
                        }
                    }]
                },
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        borderJoinStyle: "round",
                        tension: 0.9,
                        lineTension: 0.4,
                        bezierCurve : true
                    }
                }
            },
            lineTension: 0.4,
                    tension: 0.4,
            backgroundColor: "black"
        });
console.log(chart)

        chart.render();
        var xVal = dps.length + 1;
        var yVal = 15;  
        var updateInterval = 1000;
  
        var updateChart = function () {
            
            
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({x: xVal,y: yVal, color: "green"});
            
            xVal++;
            if (dps.length >  10 )
            {
                dps.shift();                
            }
            chart.data[0].options.datasets[0].lineTension = 0.4;
            chart.data[0].options.datasets[0].tension = 0.4;

            chart.render();     
  
      // update chart after specified time. 
  
  };
  
  setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);
```

I've used lineTension and tension everywhere but it still looks like a straight line.

Comment: You are using canvasjs not chartjs

Comment: You can use spline instead of line chart type for such scenario